# Как вытащить данные по году в spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, дата, spring-boot

У меня приложение на Spring-boot. Есть сущность Еvent, и в ней поле `startDate`

```
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
private Date startDate;
```

Как получить список сущностей `Event` по году из поля `startDate`

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
 @Repository
 public interface EventsRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>{
    ...
    List<Event> findByStartData_Year( Date startDate );
    ... 
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо,но не сработало! Пришлось вытаскивать простым способом Date date; // your date
// Choose time zone in which you want to interpret your Date
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
cal.setTime(date);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

Comment: Это странно. Выложите всю сущность сюда,пожалуйста.  Или если проект на github   можно просто ссылку на проект

Comment: Поставьте над полем аннотацию @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)